# Set global setOptions for Backbone.Stickit.js bindings

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-stickit

Is there any way of setting global `setOptions` for Backbone.Stickit.js?

That way I can avoid having to set `validate: true` as well as other custom options on every binding:

`bindings = {
    '.someEl': {
        observe: 'prop1'
        , setOptions: {
            validate: true
        }
    }
    , '.someOtherEl': {
        observe: 'prop2'
        , setOptions: {
            validate: true
        }
    }
    , '.yetAnotherEl': {
        observe: 'prop3'
        , setOptions: {
            validate: true
        }
    }
};`

I had seen some post about using the `*` selector with .addHandler:

```
Backbone.Stickit.addHandler({
     selector: '*',
     setOptions: {validate: true}
});
```

But that didn't work for me.

I'm sure there's a simple way that I'm missing but for now my hack was to create a method that parses my property name:

```
function stickTo(propName, options) {
    _.extend({observe: propName}, {setOptions: {validate: true}}, options);
}

...

bindings: {
    '.someEl': stickTo('prop1')
}
```

stickTo sets all my default options and takes an optional parameter that overrides my defaults...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler should have worked. I setup a fiddle which logs the arguments of Model.set to the console, every time input changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/px6UP/39/

```
Backbone.Stickit.addHandler({
    selector: '*',
    setOptions: {validate:true}
});
```

Comment: Yep, sure enough seems to be working now.  Great plugin, by the way! Is there any way to set dynamic options?

Comment: Thanks! We're thinking about dynamic options. The only thing blocking it would be if we decide to implement inheritance from super/parent views.